# What if the SQL statement does not find any 'matches' in the table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript

Using MS Access, I tried to run an SQL statement but I can't make it work in the case that the table has no records yet. Will appreciate the help! Thanks!

```
Public Function GetReferenceID(RefCode As String) As Integer
    Dim RefID As Integer
    Dim rec As Recordset

    Call connectDB
    sSQL = "select RefID from Exceptions where RefCode = '" & RefCode & "'"
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    If (Not rec.EOF And Not rec.BOF) Then
        RefID = rec.RecordCount + 1
    Else
        RefID = 1
    End If
    GetReferenceID = RefID 
End Function

Private Sub RefCode_Change()
    Dim tr As Transactions, rID As Integer
    Set tr = New Transactions
    tr.GetReferenceID (RefCode.Value)
end sub
```

---

UPDATE! There's an error on this line (**Run-time error 3464, "Data type mismatch in criteria expression**"):

```
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

...in this code:

```
Private Sub RefCode_Change()
        Dim rec As Recordset, RefID As Integer
        sSQL = "select RefID from Exceptions where RefCode = '" & RefCode.Value & "'"
        Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

        If (rec.EOF And rec.BOF) Then
            RefID = 1
        Else
            rec.MoveFirst
            RefID = rec.RecordCount + 1
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use parameteried SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks.   What if somebody feeds you a RefCode of "';drop table Exceptions;--"?

Comment: If somebody feeds him a RefCode of "';drop table Exceptions;", Access' database engine will **not** execute the drop table.

Comment: @HansUp: try this: Use parameteried SQL to avoid errors (e.g. when RefCode.Value contains a single quote) and to avoid `WHERE` clause SQL injection in Access (e.g. what if someone feeds you a RefCode of `' OR '' = '` -- ?

Comment: @Ali: you seem to be assuming RefID will be a perfect sequence i.e. that MAX(RefID) = COUNT(*), MIN(RefID) = 1, no gaps, etc. I wager you do not have constraints on this table to ensure your assumptions always hold true. But rather than add those constraints, I urge you to instead take a different approach to generating identifiers.

Comment: @onedaywhen Just to be clear, I wasn't arguing against parameters.  My point was simply that "; drop trable ... " poses no risk with Access' database engine.

Comment: @HansUp: thanks, I've learned a new word today: [A small table used for eating dinner in front of the TV; A TV Tray Table;](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Trable) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do this...

```
If (rec.EOF And rec.BOF) Then
    'empty recordset
    RefID = 1
Else
    'at least one row
     rec.movefirst
     RefID = rec.RecordCount + 1
End If
```

You could also simplify all of that to

```
RefID = Dcount("*","Exceptions","refCode='" & RefCode & "'") +1
```

Comment: Refcode is a string field. Do you know how I should fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but I see two potential issues:

1. you haven't specified your recordset declaration, so you could be running into the ambiguity between the DAO and ADO recordset types. Instead, declare your recordset variable as `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset` or `Dim rs As ADOX.Recordset` (I think that latter is correct -- I never use ADO, so never have to specify it!). The fact that `Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)` returns a data type mismatch strongly suggests to me that you have declared an ADO recordset, because that would cause a mismatch with the DAO recordset returned by CurrentDB.OpenRecordset().
2. DAO recordsets cannot be guaranteed to return an accurate Recordcount until you've traversed the entire recordset. Because of Jet/ACE's Rushmore technology, the beginning of the recordset is delivered while the end of it is still being retrieved. You could wait around for a while and hope the Recordcount is accurate, or you can explicitly make an rs.MoveLast, in which case the Recordcount will be guaranteed to be accurate.